# Compiling legacy code using iOS 7 SDK breaks app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I have a developed application and the code is compiled using Xcode 4.6 and executes on iPhone with IOS version 6.1.3 . That's all OK.

Now I am requested to test it on the iOs 7.0 or later version . Then I upgrade all needed stuff , including xcode, mac OS version ,etc. (I have to upgrade them because the original version of xcode complains of the failure that it can not compile and debug on ios7.0)....

When I try to build the code using the latest combined versions and run on ios7.0, the application is dysfunctional and the problems are mainly related to GUI-related.

But the application with xcode 4.6 built can normally run on IOS 7.0.3 phone. So I think it is feasible for the legacy code/SDK to run on ios 7.0.3. Currently, I don't have plan to upgrade the code to optimize for ios7.

So  My question is : How can I test/debug this application on iOS 7 or later ?

Thanks alot

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not getting wrong understanding from your question...And what you want is this..

1. You don't want to build your application using iOS 7 base sdk (You were using iOS 6 base sdk on xcode 4.6).
2. But you want to use latest xcode with old SDK 6.1 etc and test apps on iOS 7 Devices/Simulators

**Here is solution...**

You just need to copy 6.1 SDK(or older) from your old xCode(4.6) to latest xcode(5.x) sdk folder and set base sdk to 6.1 SDK(or older one) in project setting. 
This will let you run your app on devices with iOS 6.x or lower as they were running before also lets you test your app on iOS 7 devices without compiling with latest iOS 7 SDK.

**To achieve this..**

**1.** click on your xcode4.6 -> show package content , go to path

```
/Applications/Xcode_4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
```

This is where you will see older SDK you were using (6.1 etc). Now open same path for latest xcode 5.x and copy SDKs from old xCode path to new xCode path. OR Download it from Xcode preference -> Downloads.

**2.** Now go to project setting and set base sdk  as iOS 6.x SDK

Comment: Cool. That's really what I want to ask. I will try out your solution. BTW , Can I rate your reply ????

Comment: This is valid, but it has been known to cause some problems with Xcode 5 in certain situations so proceed with caution.  It is *not* supported or recommended by Apple.

Comment: This might fire another question : is there any difference between the code built using Xcode 4.2 + SDK 6.x and xcode5 + SDK6.x

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireless AdHoc Distribution](http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/) or simply build the IPA and install it through iTunes.  Debugging it, however, is a bit more complicated.  You will have to launch Instruments on its own and choose the already running process on the device.

Comment: My developer account is type of person......You mean : the bin file compiled from 
Legacy code + xcode 4.6 and install/debug it on ios 7 right ?